# DIV set to height:auto not displaying correctly

Tags: css, html, height

Please view my website here: http://www.budgie.richardcmpage.com/

The div style for one of my boxes (the bottom blue one) is not adjusting it's height automatically. As you can see the post is longer than one line so I want it to auto adjust to the amount. I have the wrapping/break function sorted out as you can see, I just need to the background behind it as you can see now it's not working!

```
    #article_box_outer {    
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;   
    border: 1px solid #337aa4;
    background: #42592c;    
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;  
    margin-bottom:40px; 
    margin-top:10px;    
}

#article_box_inner{
    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 1px solid #337aa4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #337aa4;
    border-right: 1px solid #337aa4;
    background: #42592c;
    top: 50px;
    right: 30px;            
}
```

Comment: Dear see my answer and try to implement that you will desired layout.

Comment: I have set it to your CSS but please look at the result now..

Comment: I have seen your site after reading your comment tour css and html structure is still same. I dont know what problem you are facing while making changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the fiddle for HTML structure and css to get the same layout and css that you want.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sH4TQ/1/

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sH4TQ/1/embedded/result/

SS:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The outer div is not behaving as you expect because of the inner div's `position: absolute;`.

This property takes the div out of the document flow and doesn't reserve its space. Remove the position, and use `margin-top: 50px;` instead.

:)

Answer (score 0):

A couple things I noticed while messing around in Firebug.

1. First. Just wondering why you have everything positioned either relatively or absolute? I don't think that this is necessary given your layout.

If you set your container to display table this seems to solve the problem. "Sort of"

```
#article_box_inner {display:table;}
```

The problem with this is that when more content is added it doesn't push this container down **#article_box_inner**

And that is because it is positioned absolutely. With this layout everything should be able to float left with out using absolute or relative positions.